# Why do my tabs in Sublime Text appear so far off in Github?

Tags: github, sublime-text

In my Sublime Text settings I have:

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

And in the editor my code looks beautiful like so (all tabs):

[image]

However in GitHub the tabbing turns out terrible:

[image]

If I use 4 spaces the code in Github turns out much better, but typing out 4 spaces vs 1 tab is not efficient :(

Is it possible to have both speed and beauty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github displays tabs as equivalent to 8 spaces. To make your code in Sublime and Github look the same, go to **`View -> Indentation`** and make sure both `Indent Using Spaces` and `Tab Width: 4` are checked. Now, when you're editing your code, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will insert 4 spaces instead of a tab character.

Comment: Ah thanks! Also I had to click the `Convert indentations to spaces` option as well, looks like I have to do that for every file now :/ but at least the results in GitHub are looking pretty finnally...

Answer (score 1):

For a permanent solution try:

- *Preferences* **>** *Settings - User*
- Insert `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`
- Save

Once you restart Sublime Text, pressing the tab key will create spaces instead of tabs. **Note that existing tabs will still be tabs.** [Use *Find and Replace All* to change all tabs to 4 spaces] This setting may also be useful:

- Change the size of tabs to match GitHub

  - `"tab_size": 8,`

The *Preferences.sublime-settings* file should then look something like:

```
{
    "tab_size": 8,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

This should be enough to keep the tabbing functionality while working with spaces without having to change settings on individual files.

Answer (score 0):

For a more complete solution check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833953/how-to-change-tab-size-on-github/33831598#33831598)

Basically, if you add an `.editorconfig` file to your project Github will display based on its settings. Much better than dealing with spaces.